# Firefox não abre modal Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, modal

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
         <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 empresa-button">
              <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" onclick="setReturnURL('link');" title="" class=" btn btn-default" data-original-title="mensagem">
                   <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#LoginContainer">
                                            Ver detalhes da empresa
                   </span>
              </button>
         </div>
```

Tudo funciona bem no Chrome, porém no Firefox não consigo abrir o modal com o clique no `<span>`

Comment: Poderia colocar o código do modal completo e do botão que faz a chamada, com o código `js`?

Comment: Que tal abrir um jsfiddle, plunker ou similar com os códigos?

Comment: @carlos vou fazer isso amanhã, e coloco o código js também